# How do you set up proxy authentication service in Ubuntu running inside vmware?

Tags: vmware, proxy

Here are the details:

I run Windows7 As Host OS.

I run Ubuntu12.04 in vmware.
I use a proxy service to connect to the  Internet in windows.

Now that proxy service asks for my username and password every time I open a website in browser.

I installed Ubuntu on vmware.

I have set up the same proxy  address (settings->network) in Mozilla Firefox  of Ubuntu.
Now whenever I open a website from Firefox in Ubuntu , it prompts me for a username and password.

I enter the password and username and I get to browse what I want in Ubuntu.

Now my problem is how do I run commands like sudo apt-get update from the terminal.

I can run nslookup from 
terminal and can find ip addresses of certain sites , but I cannot ping those sites.